# Not understanding Echo e2=e1 in Java

Tags: java

I understand the following Java outputs.

```
public class EchoTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo();
        int x = 0;
        while (x<4){
            e1.hello();
            e1.count = e1.count + 1;
            if (x==3){
                e2.count = e2.count +1;
            }
            if(x>0){
                e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
            }
            x = x+1;
            System.out.println("e1.count is " + e1.count);
            System.out.println("e2.count is " + e2.count);
        }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}

class Echo {
    int count = 0;
    void hello (){
        System.out.println ("helloooooooo..");
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 1
e2.count is 0
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 2
e2.count is 2
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 3
e2.count is 5
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 4
e2.count is 10
10
```

However when I change Echo e2 = new Echo () to Echo e2 = e1, I don't understand why the outputs is so.

```
public class EchoTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = e1;
        int x = 0;
        while (x<4){
            e1.hello();
            e1.count = e1.count + 1;
            if (x==3){
                e2.count = e2.count +1;
            }
            if(x>0){
                e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
            }
            x = x+1;
            System.out.println("e1.count is " + e1.count);
            System.out.println("e2.count is " + e2.count);
        }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}

class Echo {
    int count = 0;
    void hello (){
        System.out.println ("helloooooooo..");
    }
}
```

Output

```
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 1
e2.count is 1
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 4
e2.count is 4
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 10
e2.count is 10
helloooooooo..
e1.count is 24
e2.count is 24
24
```

To me when x = 0, e1.count is 1 and e2.count is 0.
When x = 1, e1.count is e1.count is 2 and e2.count is 2. etc.

I am hoping someone explains it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have Echo e2=e1; you make it so both e1 and e2 point to the same memory location. Thus whenever you add to e2 it adds to that memory location so e1 has the same value and vis versa. Specifically

When x = 0

```
e1.hello();
        e1.count = e1.count + 1;   //adds 1 to the memory location
        if (x==3){  // x is 0 so doesn't go in
            e2.count = e2.count +1;
        }
        if(x>0){  // x is 0 so doesn't go in
            e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
        }
        x = x+1;
        System.out.println("e1.count is " + e1.count);
        System.out.println("e2.count is " + e2.count);
    }
    System.out.println(e2.count);
}
```

Thus the memory location equals 1 and both e1 and e2 are 1

When x = 1

```
e1.hello();
        e1.count = e1.count + 1;   
           //adds 1 to the memory location which was already 1 from last time and now equals 2
        if (x==3){  // x is 1 so doesn't go in
            e2.count = e2.count +1;
        }
        if(x>0){  // x is 1 so goes in as 1 is greater than 0
            e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;  // adds e2 and e1 = 2 + 2 from previous line above = 4
        }
        x = x+1;
        System.out.println("e1.count is " + e1.count);
        System.out.println("e2.count is " + e2.count);
    }
    System.out.println(e2.count);
}
```

Thus the memory location equals 4 and both e1 and e2 are 4

Answer (score 3):

in Java variables that hold objects are really references, they do not hold the actual value. so when you write `e2 = e1` you set reference `e2` to point to the same object that `e1` does. so when you write `e2.count = 1`, the `e1.count` is set to same value, because they are fields of same object.

Answer (score 1):

After you did `Echo e2 = e1;` e1 and e2 are the same object. You just have two handles to access it, but it's the same thing and all the contents is the same. Basically, you have as many objects as many `new` statements you've executed

Answer (score 1):

Java assignments are all by reference. Thus, when you say

```
Echo e2 = e1;
```

You are saying **Make another reference labeled `e2` and point it to the same data as the reference labeled `e1`**. Then, when the data pointed to by `e1` changes, so does the data pointed to by `e2`, because **it is the same data**.

Answer (score 1):

`Echo e2 = e1` makes `e2` refer to the same object as `e1`. So from then on, you have one single object behind 2 distinct references.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `e1 = e2` you are saying that the references `e1` and `e2` point to the same `Echo` object.  So then you should treat `e1.count` and `e2.count` to be the same value.  So it goes 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 10.. etc.